# Save Foreign Key between profile model and user model

Tags: django, foreign-keys, models, user-profile

Taking first steps into `django's (1.5)` auth features and had a lot of trouble so far just attempting so pull in the user's email address (which is the username field in the user model) as a `ForeignKey` in a profile model `Specialist`.

Two questions:

1. Is this the best practice way of foreign keying to the current
   users details in a profile model?  Note, I'm not trying to save a
   new user, just associate their profile details back the their
   authenticated user object (CustomUser). By the time the user reaches
   the below view, they are already authenticated.
2. What changes are required to the below to get this to work as it
   should ?

Note, before getting this far, I hit several `user_id` **cannot be null** or **must be in instance of a CustomUser object** errors, I'm now seeing nothing is being saved in the database once I have been redirected to `/profile/`.

```
# view

@login_required
def profile_setup_specialist(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        current_user = CustomUser.objects.get(email = request.user.email)
        posted_form = SpecialistCreationForm(request.POST, instance=current_user)
        if posted_form.is_valid():
            profile = posted_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = current_user
            profile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')

            # ..


# profile model

class Specialist(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='Specialist')
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.foo

 # form

class SpecialistCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Specialist
        exclude = ['user']


# custom user model

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email           = models.EmailField(
                        verbose_name='email address',
                        max_length=255,
                        unique=True,
                        db_index=True,
                        )

    # ..

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'state']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to these issues was found by digging around in the SQLite DB, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538771/django-says-the-id-may-not-be-null-but-why-is-it).

The `manage.py sqlall` command showed the below, where the model's hidden `id` field that Django automatically creates is specified as a `PRIMARY KEY`.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "profiles_specialist" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth2_customuser" ("id"),
```

The hidden `id` field had lost its PK status somehow, and was set only as an `INTEGER` that was failing to auto increment itself each time a new object was saved.

This field needed to be reset to `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, and everything then worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I know writing custom user models are not fun, which involves writing/extending a lot of custom forms, such as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953302/django-custom-user-model-in-admin-relation-auth-user-does-not-exist/16953303#16953303). If I were to stick to the normal user model, I would say the Specialist model to have OneToOne relationship with user,

class Specialist(models.Model):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

so you can query the profile like this `request.user.specialist`

Comment: Thanks, but the custom user model is actually working fine, and I can successfully fetch the user's email address with request.user.email, it's the association back to the user model via the FK that's tripping me up.